# Prove that $(n-1)!\le n^n e^{-n}e\le n!$, where n is a positive integer.

Tags: calculus, integration

**Theorem:**

If $n$ is a positive integer Then $$(n-1)!\le n^n e^{-n}e\le n!$$

It’s from the book **Short Calculus By Serge Lang** unfortunately he didn’t make a full explanation of this theorem, he said evaluate this integral:
$$\int_1^{n} \ln (x) dx$$ and then exponentiate the result so I did this:
$$\int_1^{n} \ln (x) dx= x\ln (x)-x \Big|_1^n=n\ln(n)-n+1$$
Now exponentiating:
$$e^{n\ln(n)-n+1}=n^n e^{-n}e$$
so far everything clear but how can i find the bounds $(n-1)!$ and $n!$

Lang said that you can find them using *Upper and Lower Sums*, and using the partition $(1,2,3...n)$ but I don't know how to do this although I know what is the upper and the lower sums:
$$L_1^{n}(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(s_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(s_i)$$
where $s_i$ is the minima of function ($\ln$) in the interval $[x_{i+1}, x_i]$ so :$$L_1^{n}(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln(s_i)=\ln(\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}s_i)$$
Here I don't know how to exponentiating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a left hand sum, in this case a lower sum, of $\int_{1}^{n} \ln x dx$, you are finding $1\cdot \ln 1 + 1\cdot \ln 2 + ... + 1\cdot \ln (n-1)$ which by the laws of logarithms equals $\ln (1\cdot2\cdot...\cdot(n-1)) = \ln ((n-1)!)$.  Similarly for the right hand sum to get $\ln(n!)$.

EDIT: $\ln x$ is an increasing function, so the smallest value in an interval is always at the left edge, the lower limit, in this case the left hand sum = lower sum.

Likewise the largest value in any interval is the rightmost value for an increasing function, so the upper sum is the same as the right hand sum.

Comment: please see the edit @RobertTheTutor

Comment: Edited to expand.  You don't need to hunt for $s_i$ you know where they are, at the ends of the intervals.